# Unable to run npx for create-nuxt-app without it failing due to is-promise

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am attempting to create a nuxt app in the command line, going to build a Vue web app running off this and Vuetify. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I run the exact scaffolding command that the docs tell me to run and it errors out everytime with this message.

```
PS C:\users\gman\documents\github> npx create-nuxt-app myappname
create-nuxt-app v2.15.0
✨  Generating Nuxt.js project in myappname
Trace: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\GMan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\23248\node_modules\create-nuxt-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\GMan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\23248\node_modules\create-nuxt-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js from C:\Users\GMan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\23248\node_modules\create-nuxt-app\node_modules\run-async\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename C:\Users\GMan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\23248\node_modules\create-nuxt-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\GMan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\23248\node_modules\create-nuxt-app\node_modules\is-promise\package.json.

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1172:13)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\GMan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\23248\node_modules\create-nuxt-app\node_modules\run-async\index.js:3:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
    at C:\Users\GMan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\23248\node_modules\create-nuxt-app\cli.js:46:17
```

Has anyone else run into this, google searching is turning up nothing, figure I would check here to see if anyone know what might be up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I determined that is-promise pushed a commit 2 hours ago that broke.
They are fixing it sounds like.